# How Can I Access Xampp Projects Out Side Xampp folder(htdocs)

Tags: php, mysql, networking, xampp

we need to use project Commonly on LAN Connection so if there any networking expert here please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=================================================

## follow this step..

## step 1:

Open C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.

Un-comment line 20 (NameVirtualHost *:80).

Add your virtual host (~line 36):

```
DocumentRoot c:/your_virtual_path 

ServerName user.localhost

<Directory c:/your_virtual_path>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

===========================================================

## step 2:

Open your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).

Add

127.0.0.1 user.localhost

==============================================================

note: set your path where i write "your_virtual_path"

Now you can access that directory by browsing to http://user.localhost/

Answer (score 0):

By default, XAMPP serves any file that is located under the directory [xampp_installation_folder]/htdocs, *Â which means that you have to copy all your HTML/PHP files inside this directory. But what if you maintain a different folder for all your projects files and you want XAMPP to serve them too along with *htdocs?

Lets make XAMPP to do this.

1) Open the file [xamp_installation_folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf in any text editor.

2) Copy below lines after the *htdocs * element after changing the directory to your own folder.
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

3) Then search for this string: . Inside that element, add a new alias as followed: Alias /yoursite/ "C:/path/to/your/folder/yoursite/"

4) Save the file and restart the XAMPP server.
After this, if you have a website named 'yoursite' inside the folder 'c:/path/to/your/folder' you can access it directly by using the URL: *http://localhost:8080/yoursite/ *(assuming you have changed XAMPP port to 8080).

Hope it will help you :)